# jQuery link slashes are cutted

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a code:

```
$("#details_pics").html('<div style="background-image:url(\"'+details.images[0]+'\");background-repeat: no-repeat;background-size: cover;background-position: 0;height: 270px;"></div>');
```

But somehow it returns the link without slashes: http www.wjrlkwe.com index

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is your input string? How do you determine the output?

Comment: PROs like Guffa answer questions, others just ask another one!)))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using quotation marks around the URL without HTML encoding them, so the URL ends up outside the `style` attribute. The browser tries to parse the URL as attributes, which naturally ends up as a mess.

Use the HTML entity `&quot;` for the quotation marks:

```
$("#details_pics").html('<div style="background-image:url(&quot;'+details.images[0]+'&quot;);background-repeat: no-repeat;background-size: cover;background-position: 0;height: 270px;"></div>');
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It helped! Seems like a temporary solution, because I think somehow else it can be done. I think the problem is how to pass details.images[0]... Anyway, thank you for help!

Comment: The problem was the unencoded quotation marks in the attribute, so this is not just a temporary solution, that is what you do if you want quotation marks in an attribute. If you would have `&` characters in the URL then they would need to be encoded too, but that is not the case with your current URL.